# How to get radio button answers to show in view in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button

I'm very new to ruby on rails and haven't been able to get my radio button selections to display in my view. I can see the answers are appearing in the log but I haven't been able to get them to display in the views.

My _form.html.erb:

```
<%= f.label :_ %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:comein, "Drop Off") %>
<%= label_tag(:comein, "Drop Off") %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:comein, "Pick Up") %>
<%= label_tag(:comein, "Pick Up") %>
```

My show.html.erb view:

```
<strong>How Order Is Coming Into Office:</strong>
<%= @article.comein %>
```

My controller:

```
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
     @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
     @article = Article.new
  end

 # snippet for brevity

 def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
 end

 def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
else
render 'new'
end
end

 def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])

if @article.update(article_params)
   redirect_to @article
else
  render 'edit'
 end
end

def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
 @article.destroy

 redirect_to articles_path
end

private
  def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:number, :address, :forename, :surname,        :ordertype, :notes, :comein, :goout)
 end

 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you haven't posted the full code, you're undoubtedly using a `form_for` helper for your view, similar to the following:

```
<%= form_for @some_object do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Your selected format means that you need to use [model object helpers rather than tag helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) like `radio_button_tag`. How can you tell the difference between helper types? Tag helpers all carry a `_tag` suffix. Tag helpers are used within a `form_tag`, whereas model object helpers are used within a `form_for`, which is what you're using.

What you should be using is the [`radio_button` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button) (as well as the `label` helper).

Example:

```
<%= f.label :comein, "Pick Up", :value => "true" %><br />
<%= f.radio_button :comein, true%>
<%= f.label :comein, "Drop Up", :value => "false" %><br />
<%= f.radio_button :comein, false, :checked => true %>
```

Comment: @Mike Glad things worked out for you. If you would, please click the checkmark to the upper left of the answer to let others know what worked for you. This answer may prove as useful to someone else as it did to you.